# where to put bouncycastle jar to have it be a crypto service provider with Java JDK?

Tags: java, windows-10, bouncycastle

I installed Java SE Development Kit 16.0.2 on Windows 10 and it looks like the Java binary was installed to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`.

I'd like to install BouncyCastle as a crypto service provider and to do so I guess I need to put the Jar file in the *java-home*/jre/lib/ext/ directory. There isn't a jre directory at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` nor is there a lib directory.

So where do I put the Jar file?

Comment: Do you have a bit more context? It seems like the crypto service provider should be project specific, and you would use a tool like gradle or maven to specify the dep.

Comment: Recent version of Java (Java 9 and higher) no longer have the provided extensions mechanism. In any case, `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` would be the wrong location to look for any Java version, as it is just a location for basic executables, and not your actual Java install.

Comment: Mark is right. You need to ensure it's in the classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: For every app you run, you set up the classpath explicitly. All you need to ensure is that the bouncycastle jar is inside.

### But, isn't there a bootclasspath?

Yes; it contains things like `java.lang.String`. You can't change a JDK to have more on the bootclasspath than the standard set without hackery. You don't want this hackery.

### What about the extension mechanism?

No longer exists.

### What about the CLASSPATH environment variable?

A remnant of a bygone age. All java apps are started via launchers, IDEs or build tools that explicitly specify a classpath (in which case, `CLASSPATH` the env var is ignored), or by launching a jar, which defines its own classpath in its manifest, and again `CLASSPATH` is ignored. Java still supports the CLASSPATH environment variable. No app you ever run with a JVM should use it, though. Java supports `java.util.Vector`, even in jdk16. Doesn't mean you should use it.

### But I want a java app I did not write to use bc.

That's generally not easily possible. We're back to some fairly specific hackery.

### How do I make a jar that uses bc?

Look into how the `Class-Path` entry in jar manifests work. You can ship the bc jar in your zip file with your app (or have an installer), so that when you run your app it's in the same directory as your main app. All you'd need is `Class-Path: thatbcjar.jar` in your jar manifest and it'll be used (and that jar is resolved relative to the directory that the app jar is in, so this works no matter what the working directory is when you launch your java jar).

Comment: As I'm trying to add BouncyCastle as a _crypto service provider_ I need to modify jre/lib/security/java.security per https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablsc/index.html. I just don't know where that file is located. The Jar also needs to be relative to that for BouncyCastle to be used as a _crypto service provider_.

Comment: @neubert That is ancient documentation which relies on the extension mechanism which no longer exists. I haven't actually tried it, but recent documentation suggests that you can register a provider in the `java.security` file, and then it needs to be on the module path (or class path for a non-modularized application), or registered by provider class name: [Step 8.1: Configure the Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/howtoimplaprovider.html#GUID-831AA25F-F702-442D-A2E4-8DA6DEA16F33)

Comment: @neubert `jre/lib/security` is directly under `JAVA_HOME` folder (create the security folder if it doesn't exist), assuming you're using the JDK and not a JRE

Comment: @OneCricketeer In recent Java versions, it's `lib/security`, not `jre/lib/security`, however the config file is `conf/security`